# Change dynamic textbox border color in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm generating textboxes in angular

```
<span *ngFor="let list of lists[0].question; let i = index">
                    {{ list }}  
 <input type="text" *ngIf="i != lists[0].question.length-1" [(ngModel)]="values[i]"/>   
</span>
```

In this for loop textbox is being generated

i'm calling function on button click that get all the data from values variable

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++) {

   if(this.values[i]=='somevalue')
    {
     // change this particular textbox color
    }

 }
```

I want to change the textbox border color of that particular index only not with all the textboxes values.
Any Solution Thanks

Comment: @Freestyle09 I have updated the code Please check,  i want to change the border color of that specific textbox where index matched and `value='some_value'`

Comment: Yeah I saw it thanks

Comment: Could you please recreate this in stackblitz?

Comment: you can in the own .html use `<input type="text" [style.border-color]=values[i]=='some_value'?'red':null`..>`

Comment: @Eliseo Can i achieve that in my function i want to show it on button click and some_value is also dynamic that i'm getting in function

Comment: @Eliseo I have access to `some_value` variable in my function only not where text box is generated

Comment: I create an answer. simply call to the function in the button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to change the color when you click a button you can use a variable (if only one of them can be change the color) or and array

Only one

```
indexAttention:number=-1;
checkValue(variable:string)
{
   //better than use a "typical for just use findIndex
   this.indexAttention=this.values.findIndex(x=>x==variable)
}

//and 
<input [style.border-color]="i==indexAttention?'red':null ...>
```

If you has more you can create an array with the index of the elements. For this we can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
indexesAttention:number[]=[]
checkValue(variable:string)
{
   //map convert an array in another with the same elements and the values  calculates
   //in this case, if the value is equal to the variable
   //return the index, else return -1
   this.indexesAttention=this.values.map((x,index)=>x==variable?index:-1)
}
```

Then we write

```
<input [style.border-color]="indexesAttention.indexOf(i)>=0?'red':null ...>
```

NOTE: Is good know the differents methods to iterate in an array: find, findIndex,forEach,map... (Take a look to the [mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex))

**Update** if we want to check severals words in a list it's better that our function return an array -not change the variable-

```
checkValue(variable:string):number[]
{
   return this.values
         .map((x,index)=>x==variable?index:-1)
         .filter(x=>x!=-1) //only want the index>>-1
}
```

So we can in click function

```
   click()
   {
         this.indexesAttention=[] //clean the array
         this.lists.forEach(x=>{   //iterate using forEach

                                   //concat two arrays
           this.indexesAttention=[...this.indexesAttention,
                                  ...this.checkValue(x)]
         })
   
   }
```

Now, we are using the [spread operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#spread) to concat two arrays

NOTE: I know that there're many concepts but really, about arrays, there are no more

NOTE2: you can use also

```
<input 
[style.border-color]="lists.indexOf(values[i])>=0?'red':null"
...>
```

And you forget the functions

Comment: Thanks Yes i have multiple array like this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ekemgq?file=src/app/app.component.ts i will try your solution, how i will pass this parameter `checkValue(variable:string)` to checkValue function

Comment: answer update :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ekemgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts I implemented your code can you please check i think i have to reverse the condition of wrong and and status too so that it will work on button click only, presently if i type one two three in each textboxes then border is red but it should be opposite

Comment: indexOf return the index if find it or -1 if not find it. simply change the condition by `indexesAttention.indexOf(i)<0?'red':null`. BTW Are you think about use a [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms)?